# Western Digital My Passport how is data stored

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a Western Digital My Passport (external hard drive) and I had been using it to back up my Windows XP machine. The XP machine's hard drive crashed, so now I am left with the My Passport drive.

Will I be able to load My Passport onto a Windows 7 machine? What about a Mac? Does anyone have any experience with this?  Was it a bad idea to use the Western Digital My Passport software?

Any input would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have any trouble reading the drive using a Windows 7 machine.

You shouldn't have any trouble reading the drive on a Mac either. If the drive was formatted using FAT32, which is likely the default, a Mac can read and write just fine to it. If it's formatted NTFS, which is the Windows standard, [it should be able to read, but not write.](https://superuser.com/questions/40241/should-a-mac-mount-an-usb-external-ntfs-drive-by-default)

Comment: Macs should read NTFS fine; you may need additional software to *write* to it.  see this answer for more: http://superuser.com/questions/53633/create-a-shared-fat32-partition-on-boot-camp-macbook/53714#53714

Comment: I actually found a similar question at the same time, and updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: But does "My Passport" store the data in its own compressed format?  I am afraid that the crappy "My Passport" software will need to be compatible with the OS in order to read the data.  Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: It's very doubtful. I've never used the software myself, but I'd expect it to just be copying data straight over to the drive. If anything, it'd compress it into a known format, such as .zip. I see no reason why they'd reinvent the wheel just to prevent compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my Western Digtal Passport WDXMS2500 is **NOT** compatible with Windows 7...I don't know why exactly.  But it cannot connect...and who knows if it ever will.

Comment: That's not possible, unless you've encrypted the WD Passport.

Comment: According to WD tech support it will not work under Win 7 at this time.  I didn't encrypt it either.  Not sure what kind of magic they do on those drives...but I have moved to from Vista to Vista box with no problem but it does not work on two Win 7 machines I've tried to use.

Comment: link to Discussion on subject...starts off during beta but last post was recent...still problems.
http://i.nconspicuo.us/2009/02/05/windows-7-not-recognizing-external-hard-drive-western-digital-mybook/

Comment: It seems quite unbelievable that an external USB drive would need special (non-generic) drivers. My own WD Passport works very well on Win7.

Comment: I concur yet there it seems to be.  I'm building another machine today and going to try it again on that one to see.

Comment: Just got around to rebuilding this machine...and this go around it worked without a hitch...go figure.