# Transferring dmg files from a PC to an Apple

Tags: windows, macos, file-transfer

I have dmg files on my computer that I need to put on my friends new Macbook. When I try to put the files on an external hard drive it says that they are too large to transfer (each file is about 8 gigs).

Just trying to figure out the best way to do this transfer. We started doing it with an Ethernet cable last night, and transferred about 8 gigs over the course of a couple of hours.

Answer (score 2):

What filesystem does your external hard drive use?

Typically external media such as flash drives and external hard drives use the FAT32 filesystem because it easily interoperates with both Macs, Windows and Linux.

FAT32, however, has a 4GB file size limit.  You could reformat your hard drive to use NTFS (on your Windows machine) which supports larger file sizes and according to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/40241/should-a-mac-mount-an-usb-external-ntfs-drive-by-default) your Mac should be able to read the files just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As heavyD said, this is most likely down to Filesystem limitations - most external media is pre formatted with Fat.

Personally, as much as Windows shares are supported, I sometimes find it more trouble than it is worth to set up.

If you can put both computers on the same network, the quickest thing you can do is simply install a FTP server on your PC such as [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server) (which is free), then create a new user with a home directory of the place with the `.DMG` Files.

You may need to unblock FTP on your system firewall.

Next, on the Apple machine, simply go to the ftp location and you should be able to transfer direct from machine to machine!